RDLC report overlay text on image layout issue
I am creating an RDLC report in .NET framework 4.8 with text overlay on an image. Requirement is to create a report to submit to federal gov in a specific format. That is why I am using the text overlay on image model. I was able to create report and export to PDF everything working fine, except textbox layout is changing in PDF export.
First I add a List(Tablix-BaseTable) then add a rectangle(BaseRectangle) in it then another rectangle for each page(Page1,2...) and setting the background image of Page1 rectangle to the image and adding the textboxes.
Image in RDLC design
Image after rendering in PDF
Is there any workaround for this issue
